# Заставка во время подключения и ожидания Android

Tags: java, android, activity, экран

Приложение при старте подключается к серваку и берет из него данные. Этот процесс происходит какое-то время и асинхронно.

Во время загрузки вместо контента активити должна быть какая-либо заставка во весь экран, а при окончании активити заполняется контентом.

Вопрос: как ЛАКОНИЧНО и быстро менять все содержимое экрана? Не вызывать же новую Activity. Как это делали вы?

Comment: нет ничего плохого в использовании SplashActivity. Можно использовать еще progressDialog, если загружаете список, то используйте swypeRefreshLayout компонент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Типовое решение вашего вопроса - как раз вызывать новую активити.

Если на время ожидания требуется предоставлять статическую картинку (без взаимодействия с пользователем), то можно просто подготовить нужную разметку и перед запуском запроса данных с сервера, установить ее через `setContentView()`, после получения данных этим же методом установить основную разметку.
Так же следует предусмотреть обработку поворотов, чтобы при этом не происходила подмена разметок и во время выполнения бизнес-логики всегда была активна только основная разметка.

Для динамического взаимодействия (например, что то вроде кнопки "Нажмите, чтобы продолжить") такой способ не подходит, в силу множества подводных камней и крайней костыльности реализации на практике - в этом случае делается отдельная *Splash Activity*

Answer (score 0):

Может не особо в тему, применительно к Вашему проекту... Первая мысль которая приходит в голову:

Добавить в проект простую html страницу, допустим с заставкой на js или видео в main активити в качестве блока, + скрипт проверки готовности данных на сервере, и скрыть содержимое этого блока в случае успеха.

Оговорюсь, я делал простенькие приложения которые либо подтягивали сайт в net view, либо собирал не нативное приложение используя jquery mobile и html в качестве сайта внутри проекта, так что вышенаписанное может быть не применимо в Вашем случае.

Comment: Это точно не решение для "нативной" разработки под андроид.